# Unity3D Command line Build not accessing libraries and updating Android Manifest

Tags: android, xml, command-line, build, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project with multiple android plugins. 
The plugins are placed in the recommended folders /Assets/Plugins/Android/NameOfPlugin and each have their own AndroidManifest.xml and .project file. 
I also have an AndroidManifest.xml in /Assets/Plugins/Android

When building out a .apk from any of the dev machines in studio, the AndroidManifest is correctly compiled into a single .xml file containing all required activities. 
However, when building on a Mac Mini via commandline this does not happen. The AndroidManifest.xml is missing required code and the app doesn't work.

I have done fresh installs of everything, tried different configurations, loads of things but to no avail. Anyone have any ideas as to what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of Dan's colleagues here, and after doing a straight up text diff on the two "Editor.log" files of Unity's editor, there was one glaring line that was missing from the broken builder,

```
DisplayProgressbar: Android Library Support
```

Googling that lead me to http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/792979/android-library-support-build-issue.html who had already discovered the answer, which was damn near exactly the same as what we had suffered,

> It appears having a "." in the name of a directory on the build path results in failure of the android-libraries to be correctly found and added to the StagingArea.
>
> Moving our repository on the Autobuilder from ~/.jenkins/workspace/game_project to ~/game_project fixed the issue.

We've just done the same ourselves, and it's solved the issue.